# MS Access conditional formatting values stored in field of table?

Tags: ms-access-2010, conditional-formatting

I have searched through various forums to find an example of a conditional formatting that uses the values for a background color which are stored in a field in the table.

My work uses monthly colors to put items on half off sale,
12 months 12 colors, so 1st off useing the ribbon won't work. (Oh yea its MS OFFICE 2010 professional version of Access)

I will be printing barcoded SKUs with department names, price, and then the Month name. The month name will have gray background for November. In December all gray tags are half off.

The problem can be solved in VBA as this example from [access-programmers.co.uk](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=192303)shows, but it is hardcoded into the module.  I.e.

```vbs
Select Case Me.CarID  'the name of the control with the value to be tested
  Case "TILX"
    Me.TextBoxName.BackColor = 12632256  '(gray)
  Case "GATX"
    Me.TextBoxName.BackColor = vbRed
  Case Else
    Me.TextBoxName.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)  '(white)
End Select
```

I have the month table like so:

```
MonthCode  MonthName  MonthColor
---------  ---------  ----------
11         November     12632256
```

This way the color values are stored dynamicly (in case peach paper or pink ink is a billion times cheaper in the future) but the background property of the textbox of the MonthName has no event builder just a pallet selection (or I would have tried `=[monthTable]![MonthColor]`).

So,

a. Should I use the VBA example and test each case? or

b. Can I use the field value as the uhm value in an expression for me.Textbox. MonthName=[MonthColor]?

I only get about twenty uninterrupted seconds at the computer with Access on it to experiment, between my cashiering, pricing, receiving, and inventorying. So i truly appreciate your previous experience.

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Since you had the foresight to put the desired colour values into a table, all you need now is a `DLookup()`. For example, in the `On Format` event handler of the report's Detail band we can do

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Me.MonthName.BackColor = DLookup("MonthColor", "MonthTable", "MonthCode=" & Month(Me.txtSomeDate))
End Sub
```

which produces

[image: MonthColors.png]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Obviously it works for you. After getting to work, I realized my report is based on a query, and none of the fields are named the same nor are in "Camel Case"! So I quickly created a new table with the same field names I gave in the question, and created a report on this table.Could you add a screen shot to show me where you've typed the expression into.  there is no On Format event on the properties tool box, for my report.  There is one named format, but after inserting code into it, it does some bizarre substitutions to what I've pasted.

Comment: @user2978151 You can download my test database from [here](http://wikisend.com/download/309710/rainbow.zip). It includes a macro to open the report in Print Preview mode (so you can see the colours). Open the report in Design View to see how it was put together. BTW, the `On Format` property in question is a property of the `Detail band` of the report, not a property of the text box control or the report as a whole.

Comment: Oh! I found it, I admit I never new the Detail Band had properties.