# MS Access - VBA Conditional Formatting using RGB Codes stored in a table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report with the following TextBox control in the Detail section.
Each of the control's is linked to a DataSource stored in a table (tblStages).

Report Control Names:

- `txtStageName`
- `txtColorCode`

I want to programmatically Conditionally format the `txtColorCode` control's `BackColor` and `ForeColor` properties based on the values stored in the table "tblStages".

TABLE EXAMPLE:

| StageName | RGBCode |
| --- | --- |
| Perimeter | `RGB(255, 108, 0)` |
| Void | `RGB(0, 38, 255)` |

So, if the `txtStageName = "Permieter"` then I want the `txtColorCode` control to format the `BackColor` and `ForeColor` to `RGB(255, 108, 0)`

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried implemented the following Sub routine on the report in question.
This is an alteration of the code found here: [MS Access conditional formatting values stored in field of table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900971/ms-access-conditional-formatting-values-stored-in-field-of-table)

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)

    Me.ColorCode.BackColor = DLookup("RGBCode", "tblStages", "StageName=" & Me.StageName)
    Me.ColorCode.ForeColor = DLookup("RGBCode", "tblStages", "StageName=" & Me.StageName)
    
End Sub
```

This resulted in no errors being produced however formatting was not applied to the field.

Comment: Uhm, if both the `ForeColor` **and** `BackColor` are both `255,108,0` then the text will be unreadable.

Comment: Also... why are you using Hungarian Notation?

Comment: Hi,
The ForeColor and BackColor is intentionally the same. I do not want the text to be readable.

Comment: Why not just disable the control then?

Comment: The control is disabled.
An additional field on the report displays the information the end user needs to see.
It is just a visual reference.

The txtColorCode is just a box containing the color that is related to the data in txtStageName.

I just need to know how to apply the formatting in VBA as the built in Conditional Formatting dialog will not work as additional records in the table will be added frequently and this should automate the conditional formatting process.

Comment: Why not set Visible property instead? Do you want border to show?

Comment: Are you opening report in ReportView or PrintPreview? Format event executes only for PrintPreview or direct to printer.

Answer (score 1):

Those color properties when set in VBA are expecting a color code as a decimal number (27903) or a hexadecimal string with `&H` prefix ("&H006CFF").

RGB() is a function that returns decimal equivalent. Calling the RGB function and arguments from a text field as you attempt won't work directly. All you are pulling is a literal string "RGB(255, 108, 0)", not executing a function with arguments.

If you want to use RGB(), save the RGB codes like: **255,108,0**. Then when retrieved from table, parse the parts into separate elements that can be fed to the RGB() function.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Dim strC As String
    strC = DLookup("RGBCode", "tblStages", "StageName=" & Me.StageName)
    Me.ColorCode.BackColor = RGB(Split(strC, ",")(0), Split(strC, ",")(1), Split(strC, ",")(2))
    Me.ColorCode.ForeColor = RGB(Split(strC, ",")(0), Split(strC, ",")(1), Split(strC, ",")(2))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that.
I managed to figure this out also just before updating this